# Unable to connect to scanner (simple-scan & Brother DCP-L2530DW)

Tags: scanner, brother, simplescan

I'm using simple-scan with a Brother DCP-L2530DW printer/scanner. The printer works fine, but I'm having issues using the scanner.

I've installed the drivers:

```
jam@jam-ncase:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep Brother
[sudo] password for jamie: 
ii  brscan-skey                                0.2.4-1                                amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan4                                    0.4.8-1                                amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  dcpl2530dwpdrv:i386                        4.0.0-1                                i386         Brother DCP-L2530DW printer driver (lpd/cups)
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                     5-1                                    amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                      1.4.2-3                                amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

When I start simple-scan, it says `Ready to Scan - Brother DCP-L2530DW`.

But when I click scan, the scanning animation starts, but then an error message pops up saying: `Failed to scan, unable to connect to scanner`.

I've googled the problem, and the things I've tried are:

- add my user to `lp`
- Running this command: `sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`

Comment: Please update your post with the version of Ubuntu you were using when you wrote this.  The bug mentioned by @Boorhin affects 20.04, but I'm having a similar problem to yours using 18.04.  Knowing your version will help determine the source of our errors.

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick on Ubuntu 20.04 for a brother MFC-L2710DW

```
sudo apt purge ippusbxd
```

references
https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1871011

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ippusbxd/+bug/1876289

Comment: Please update your answer with 1) the version of Ubuntu you were using when this solution worked and 2) the brand of printer/scanner you were using.  This will help me determine if the bug you've linked might be relevant to my 18.04 system using a Brother scanner.

Comment: Edited my answer